# How do I POST data to dataverse lookup column?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dataverse, power-platform

The code looks like that:

```
jsonlistdf  = {'column1': '0000098778', 'lookupcolumn': '5187', 'column2': 'Lodon', 'column3': '8000'}

   conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("{}.api.crm4.dynamics.com".format(url))

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +accesstoken,
    'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',  
    'OData-Version': '4.0',  
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Prefer': 'return=representation'

}

for i in jsonlistdf:
  data = json.dumps(i, default=str)
  response = conn.request("POST", "/api/data/v9.2/tablewithlookupcolumn", data, headers)
  res = conn.getresponse()
  data = res.read()
  print(res.status, res.reason)
```

When I remove the lookupcolumn from the data, it will be posted to dataverse without any problems.

I have understood from the documentation that i need to use the GUI from the lookup column table. The lookup column table is account table. In account table there is the accountid_guid. So how should I use it and where ?

Comment: use my tool Dataverse REST Builder https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB to check the exact syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it goes like that:

The look up table is connected with some other table so you can't directly post any messages there, what you can do is get the GUID from the other dataverse table.

Then you create a away to connect your data here is an example:

In my case the source table row GUID which needs to match with other table is "436047e5-c37a-ed11-81ad-000d3a46f784"

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("{}.api.crm4.dynamics.com".format(url))
    
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +accesstoken,
    'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',  
    'OData-Version': '4.0',  
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Prefer': 'return=representation',
    'If-Match': '*'

}


payload = "{\"kgt_loc\":\"m1,k2,uN1,k9\",\"kgt_main\":\"0000,0000,\"}"
#payload = "{\"kgt_month\":\"February\"}"


#kgt_accountsegmentid is in the url
reponse = conn.request("PATCH", "/api/data/v9.2/kgt_lookuptable(436047e5-c37a-ed11-81ad-000d3a46f784)", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data)
print(res.status, res.reason)
```

This works well to update the tables

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. This is how I've solved it:

I am posting into table named 'ReferralDetails' and matching the lookup with another table called 'Referrals'.

The column name of the lookup would be formatted like this:

```
"ReferralLookup@odata.bind"
```

ReferralLookup is the so called 'Schema name' of the column, with capital letters in my case (not the Logical name which is automatically lowercase).

The value to be posted would be:

```
"referralses(GUID)"
```

where referralses is the table name that I named 'Referrals' and Microsoft turned into plural unfortunately. And GUID is the unique ID of the a single entry in 'Referrals'.

Posting into URL:

```
https://...dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/referraldetailses
```

(table name turned into plural too and lowercase)

And these are the headers:

```
'Authorization' = <your-token>,
'Content-Type' = 'text/plain',
'OData-Version' = '4.0',
'OData-MaxVersion' = '4.0',
'Content-Type' = 'application/json',
'If-None-Match' = NULL
```

Have fun!